# Azure website custom domain name

Tags: wordpress, azure, vanity-url

I've begun setting up my first Azure website. I began with Free website version to learn how to setup a WordPress site. Next I promoted the site to Azure Shared, to enable me to setup a custom domain name. I struggled to setup a vanity domain name but this is now active. 
However the site resources are loading cloudhound.azurewebsites.net and not the custom domain to www.cloudhound.co.uk. 
How do I set the database to point to the new domain?
A plugin Better Search Replace plugin suggests I can update URLs or other text in a database. My question is do I enter cloudhound.azurewebsites.net/home/ in the search box and in the REPLACE BOX enter cloudhound.co.uk OR do I enter in the search box //www.cloudhound.azurewebsites.net/home/ and in the REPLACE BOX //www.cloudhound.co.uk perhaps both? Would I need to add http:// Thank you.

[site error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIApi.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your site is a Wordpress, you have to also set up the primary domain in Wordpress for it to show up. There's a way to do it with the files - http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL But, the easiest way is just to go into Settings -> General from your Wordpress dash board and update the URL that's there.